# Problem when calling function into another module in python

Tags: python, function, module, chess, method-call

I'm creating a chess game within python. It contains 2 modules - one, called main.py, contains the setup of the game, and also controls user input. The other module, called chess.py, determines the valid moves that can be made each turn, and stores the current condition of the game.
I am trying to determine the list of legal moves that can be made each turn. The list is empty for now, but as it is declared in the chess module, and executed in the main module, I run into a circular dependency when trying to call the function into the main module.

Here is the function written in the chess module:

```
def legalMoves(self):
    moveList = []
    print (self.startSquare)
    pieceColour = self.board[self.startSquare[0]]
    pieceType = self.board[self.startSquare[1]]
    for row in range(8):
      for col in range(8):
        if pieceColour == 'w' and self.whiteTurn == True or pieceColour == 'b' and self.whiteTurn == False:
          if pieceType == 'p':
             self.pawnMoves()
```

self.board is a visualisation of the chess board as a 2-dimensional list. It is contained in its own class called chessboard, which is also in the chess module. Its purpose is to iterate through the list and, based on the characters in each index, draw the corresponding chess piece on each square.

```
class chessboard(
):  #creates a chessboard visualised through a 2D list. This list will determine the positions and types of pieces on the board

    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [
            ['bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR'],
            ['bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp'],
            ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
            ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
            ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
            ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
            ['wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp'],
            ['wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR'],
        ]
```

The code that runs this function in main is:

```
legalMoves = chess.legalMoves(self)
```

However, when I run the program, I immediately run into this error:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I'm hoping for the function to pass as normal, since there are no errors like this when other functions in my program use the self parameter. Online tutorials I have checked don't seem to run into this problem either, they can pass functions to other modules just fine.

The function is not inside a class, I tried putting it into the class and calling said class into the main module that way, but I appear to get the exact same error when attempting this.

Have I run into a circular dependency? Any suggestions to fix this problem?

Comment: What is `self`? What is `self.board`?

Comment: _The function is not inside a class_ Really?  Because it sure looks like it should be...

Comment: `self` is the instance of the class that `legalMoves` is attached to. If you don't have a class, then don't use `self`. Instead explicitly pass in the data that the function needs.

Comment: @quamrana self is what I have used to refer to attributes of other classes in the module. I've found that by referring to variables using self.variableName, I only need to pass self as a parameter instead of the many variables that I would usually need to pass in.

self.board is a 2D list earlier in my program that represents the chessboard.
It's too long to add in this comment so I'll make a new comment and add it in there. My program essentially iterates through the list and looks at the corresponding values of each index, which determines where the pieces should be drawn on the board.

Comment: @quamrana self.board = [
            ['bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR'],
            ['bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp'],
            ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
            ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
            ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
            ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
            ['wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp'],
            ['wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR'],
        ]

Comment: Where is this assignment located? You need to include a lot more code so we can see what the execution sequence is. Please update your question with the relevant code. Don't put code in comments.

Comment: @JohnGordon Placing the function inside a new class and importing that class into the module seems to have removed the error for now. Thanks for the help. It's worth noting that I am quite new to classes, so that's probably why it was such a simple fix.

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding about how classes and objects work. We won't be able to untangle this until we understand exactly how you misunderstand.

Comment: @quamrana my question has been updated accordingly. Its worth noting that my initial question has now been fixed due to the help of a different commenter, but I would appreciate any extra help or criticisms of my code you could provide, as I do indeed seem to have an issue with understanding how classes work.

Comment: Yes, if you have `class chessboard:`, then it sounds like `def legalMoves(self):` should be part of that. So, it also sounds like you have: `chess = chessboard()`. If so, then your call should be: `legalMoves = chess.legalMoves()` or simply: `chess.legalMoves()` as there is no `return`

Answer (score -1):

You do not include self.  Self is defined by the namespace.

```
legalMoves = chess.legalMoves()
```

`legalMoves` is the namespace.

This is assuming chess is the called class, and your method `legalMoves` is inside that class.  Otherwise you shouldn't be using `self` at all.

If you are bringing legalMoves in from a chess.py, then you do not need self, and define your function without the variable `self`

Comment: Surely this will result in a `missing 1 required argument` error? The OP seems to say that `chess` is a module name.

Comment: Clearly legalMoves is part of the class `chess`.  Or his entire code is nonsensical.

Comment: What class? I see no class.

Comment: Do you see `board` or `startsquare`?  OBVIOUSLY the code is not complete.  Maybe learn to program before you criticize?

Comment: What do you mean by "namespace"? You are making a lot of assumptions about what the OP actually has in their code.

Comment: I am making assumptions because the code is/was incomplete.  My answer is solid, why not produce an actual answer instead?  If you don't know what a namespace is, then ask a new question.